# Javascript, check if array contains a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm pushing some anonymous functions into an array this way:

```
myArray.push(function(){ /* some cool code here */});
myArray.push(function(){ /* some cooler code here */});
```

Then I execute all functions doing

```
while (myArray.length) { myArray.shift().call();}
```

The question is: how can I check if a function is already into `myArray`? I Tried to do a comparison using `toSource()` but it does not work... Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a specific function or any function?

Comment: @kristjanreinhold that definitely would not work.

Comment: @Mritunjay :I need to avoid pushing the same function twice into `myArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your comparison of the functions as a string:

`func1.toString() === func2.toString()`

This will even work with anonymous functions, but assumes that by equivalent you mean having the same code, character for character.

Comment: I was imagining a situation where you would potentially add the same function in terms of having the exact same code, however you bring up a good point with that example. Two functions given the same input that would produce the same output, would not be shown as equal with this method. I guess you have to define what makes two functions equivalent.

Comment: I think that would be overkill and could be near impossible to do in many cases. I imagine this would suit the OP's purpose.

Comment: As I said, I'm only pushing anonymous functions into `myArray`, so your answer seems to suit my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf` to check whether your array has that function or not:

```
var foo = function () {};
var bar = function () {};
var arr = [];

var addFunction = function (f) {
    if (arr.indexOf(fn) === -1) {
        arr.push(fn);
    }
};

addFunction(foo);
addFunction(foo);
console.log(arr.indexOf(foo));    // prints 0
console.log(arr.indexOf(bar));    // prints -1
```

You can also create a map to check whether you added this function or not:

```
var foo = function foo() {};
var bar = function bar() {};
var arr = [];
var map = {};

var addFunction (fn) {
    if (!map[fn.name]) {
        arr.push(fn);
        map[fn.name] = fn;
    }
};

addFunction(foo);
addFunction(foo);
console.log(arr.indexOf(foo), map['foo']);    // prints 0, function foo() { ... }
console.log(arr.indexOf(bar), map['bar']);    // prints -1, undefined
```

**Note:** This second example might not work with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

As you're adding functions to the list, keep a separate object in which you record some sort of identifier that allows you to check whether the function has been added to the array:

```
  var myArray = [], addedFunctions = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < whatever; ++i) {
     // do whatever
     if (something) {
       if (!addedFunctions[ "cool code 1" ]) {
         myArray.push(function() { /* cool code 1 */ });
         addedFunctions[ "cool code 1" ] = true;
       }
     }

     if (somethingElse) {
       if (!addedFunctions[ "cool code 2" ]) {
         myArray.push(function() { /* cool code 2 */ });
         addedFunctions[ "cool code 2" ] = true;
       }
     }
  }
```